# VS2019 + CMake: Cannot select static library as startup target

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm developing audio plugins (so, dlls) that are loaded in external programs.
When using the non-cmake version of a project, I used to debug my dlls by modifying the debugging command of the dll target, so that the external program would be run, which then in turn loads the dll I'm debugging (target -> Properties -> Debugging -> Command)

It seems like with the cmake-version of the project this is not possible any more, since it only allows debugging of executable targets. While this makes sense intuitively, in my case this prevents me from testing my dll.

Is there any way of adding a custom debug target?

Comment: I have never heard of debugging non-executable targets. At most you can write an executable tester that runs the dll - which is how normally people debug them.

Comment: For normal workflows this is certainly a good idea, and i also have a unit-test executable target. However since i'm doing audio development i and there are a lot of things to be considered, i found it extremely useful to debug it in a real-world scenario.

Comment: If the approach works in a non-cmake vs project, you may be able to achieve the same effect by setting the [`VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/VS_DEBUGGER_COMMAND.html) target property. Of course using `add_custom_target` is an option. Alternatively may be an you could add a test; VS only provides a single target for running all tests at once though...